# Running both MongoDB and Mysql on Rails 2.3.6

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

In Rails 2.3.6 I'm trying to use both MongoDb via MongoMapper and Mysql on the same application.

I've seen several others question about this but I cannot find how to configure rails to use both database in the same app.

How should I configure my database.yml file?
Right now it is:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blinddog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blinddog_rails_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: blinddog_rails_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Should I add some intializers?

Thanks in advance,
Augusto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would use active record and standard database.yml file.  You would also run rails g mongo_mapper:config to create your mongo.yml file.  These are seperate and should allow you to use both in your model.  This would work for mongoid too.

Comment: Thanks!  But does "rails g mongo_mapper:config" work on rails 2.3.6?  It sounds Rails 3...

Comment: I found the solution here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper